# Replace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application by ClosedXML

Tags: excel, migration, .net-6.0, closedxml

I migrate project which operates with Excel files from .NET Framework into .NET6. Firstly I was succeeded by referencing Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly by COM references, but we have pipelines running on Linux, so it always crashed because of not possible to compile COMs by MSBuild.

I migrate project where is implemented Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly to ClosedXML assembly and cannot find a replacement for Excel.Application property.

Would somebody please know what is proper implementation for this property ?

I went through documentation of ClosedXML library and didn't find a single mention about replacement.